# How to run chkdsk on drive without command prompt in c#

Tags: c#

I searched on internet and found many possible ways of running chkdsk utility in c# using cmd.exe as file name and passing command as /c chkdsk drive_letter:/f /x

But I want to run chkdsk utility on drive ,without involvement of cmd.exe i.e; Purely using internal features of c#.

Your suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't believe chkdsk is available as a standalone .Net library. What you could do however, is to start cmd as a Process, with chkdsk as parameter, and then redirect the OutputStream to a stream in your application. That way you can read and parse whatever information CMD outputs.

Answer (score 1):

Chkdsk is a console application. So how do you wanna start a console application without the console? The only thing you can do is **hiding** the window from the user.

As you for sure already noticed: [MSDN - Chkdsk](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f9dd591d-d676-40a3-a48c-7987ed8e2ee9/execute-chkdsk-and-display-its-output-in-c)
According the console-window:

```
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
```

This together should bring you to your goal.